# Create an error message in R that also identifies non-matching values

Tags: r, if-statement

I am writing a rather long function that requires that all colnames(abun) are present in rownames(x) but not vice versa. If the requirement is not met I have designed it so that the function throws an error message. Along with the error message I would also like to tell the user which colnames(abun) are not in rownames(x). Any ideas? My current stop and error message looks like this:

```
abun <- matrix(c(0.4,0,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.5), 
    nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), 
    c("A","B","E")))

abun
    A   B   E
x 0.4 0.0 0.6
y 0.1 0.4 0.5

x<-data.frame("Trait1" =c(1,1,0,1),
                    "Trait2"=c(1,1,1,1),
                    "Trait3" =c(1,1,0,1),
                    "Trait4" =c(1,0,1,1))
rownames(x)<-c("A","B","C","D") 

x
  Trait1 Trait2 Trait3 Trait4
A      1      1      1      1
B      1      1      1      0
C      0      1      0      1
D      1      1      1      1               



if(any(colnames(abun) %in% rownames(x) != TRUE))
stop("The following species names in abun are missing trait information")
```

Answer (score 2):

Going back to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132633/test-if-col-names-are-in-row-names-in-r/19132678#19132678)

```
colnames(abun)[
    !colnames(abun) %in% rownames(x)
    ]
```

This should return the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
if(any(colnames(abun) %in% rownames(x) != TRUE))
stop("The following species names in abun are missing trait information:",
     paste(setdiff(colnames(abun), rownames(x)), collapse=" "))
```

With thanks to @Hadley for suggesting setdiff!

Comment: Thanks. This works however if there are more than one colnames(abun) not in rownames(x)it repeats the long text in front of each species name instead of just once and then a list of species names. Is there anyway to adjust this? Thanks again!

Comment: @Elizabeth, you're right. Just edited my answer, this should work.

Comment: I think using `setdiff()` would be clearer, and you can pass multiple strings to `stop()` - you don't need to put in a vector